# Angular upload file error with IE9 ieframe.dll

Tags: angularjs, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I'm using angular-upload to handle file uploads in an application, served over HTTPS. Angular-upload is set up to "fall back to iframe upload when FormData isn't supported," but the combination of using iframe for uploading over HTTPS in IE9 is causing the following errors to appear in the console:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/forbidframing.htm 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/ErrorPageTemplate.css 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/errorPageStrings.js 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/httpErrorPagesScripts.js 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/red_x.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/background_gradient.jpg
```

I've tried adding *add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN"* to the custom headers in the web.config, as well as removing *add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000"*, but neither of these approaches has changed the outcome.

Aside from refusing to support IE9 (not an option in this case), any other ideas how to make angular-upload play nicely with HTTPS/iframe in IE9?

**UPDATE** I was able to partially solve the problem by tagging the web api method with [AllowAnonymous]. The uploaded file is now accepted, but a related problem has arisen:

1) I can see on the "Network" monitor that there is a response coming back from the server, as intended

2) However, the monitor shows the request in a perpetually "Pending" status, so that response data never makes it back to the Angular controller, and therefore never updates the UI

3) The same list of errors shown above continue to show in the console

Comment: Fiddler did indeed show that the X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY" header was not being removed. Thanks for that! The request completes correctly, but now the issue is that IE9 is treating the serialized data response as a file to be downloaded, rather than rendering it to the UI. There must be another header correction I need to make.

Comment: Correct. Had to make some changes in the web api config to send back text/html where json is not supported. What a mess. If you leave your initial comment as an answer, I'll accept it, since x-frame headers were my main issue, and Fiddler helped me sniff it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages show that your subframe has an `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` header that prevents it from being framed. You need to fix that; use Fiddler to verify that the header is properly removed.

Also note that IE will treat `application/json` as a file download and won't render it inline.